# How to map results returned from Named Native query to a pojo(not entity) class fields

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

We have a Hibernate Mapping xml containing queries. We want to map the results returned by a query to a Pojo class which is not an entity class , containing all the fields returned by the query. Below is the query :

SELECT distinct FMT_NAME( pers.id ) AS customer_name,      first_name,      mid_name,   last_name,      addr.line_1_addr,   addr.line_2_addr,   RTRIM( LTRIM( addr.city_name || ', ' || addr.state_code || ' ' ||   addr.zip_code_num, ', ') || '-' || addr.zip_code_suffix, '-' ) AS line_3_addr   FROM    PERS , CASE_PERS, CASE_ADDR, ADDR   WHERE   PERS.ID = CASE_PERS.PERS_ID     AND CASE_PERS.CASE_ID = CASE_ADDR.CASE_ID   AND CASE_ADDR.ADDR_ID = ADDR.ID     AND ( TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE( TO_CHAR( CASE_ADDR.BEG_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY' )    AND CASE_ADDR.END_DATE)     AND PERS.ID = ?
We have a POjo class PersAddr which we want to map to the reults returned by the query so that we can clearly get the results which value belongs to which field and we can access those values returned by query from the getters of the pojo class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@SqlResultSetMapping` annotation for this purpose like this:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "my_query",
    query =
        "SELECT distinct FMT_NAME( pers.id ) AS customer_name, first_name, mid_name, last_name, addr.line_1_addr, addr.line_2_addr, RTRIM( LTRIM( addr.city_name || ', ' || addr.state_code || ' ' || addr.zip_code_num, ', ') || '-' || addr.zip_code_suffix, '-' ) AS line_3_addr FROM PERS , CASE_PERS, CASE_ADDR, ADDR WHERE PERS.ID = CASE_PERS.PERS_ID AND CASE_PERS.CASE_ID = CASE_ADDR.CASE_ID AND CASE_ADDR.ADDR_ID = ADDR.ID AND ( TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE( TO_CHAR( CASE_ADDR.BEG_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) AND CASE_ADDR.END_DATE) AND PERS.ID = ?",
    resultSetMapping = "my_query_dto"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "my_query_dto",
    classes = @ConstructorResult(
        targetClass = PersAddr.class,
        columns = {
            @ColumnResult(name = "customer_name", type = String.class),
            // Other column results...
        }
    )
)
```